# Manual Query String Debug

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to test against query strings, I have never done so before. And i'm a little lost.
This is my code:

```
public const string QS_UseCurrentTerm = "UCT";
if (((Page.Request.QueryString[QS_UseCurrentTerm] != null)))
    Code...
```

To test this i need to open a browser and type

```
http://localhost/sandbox?
```

But i don't know how to test against it, I tried "localhost/sandbox?UCT but the debugger just skips over this line.
can anyone let me know how i would go about testing it from within' a browser? 
Thanks

Comment: Querystrings are key-value pairs. In typing in the browser, you'd have to include the value, i.e. `localhost/sandbox?UCT=123`, where UCT is the key, and 123 is the value

Comment: You can add this in the project properties for start-up page. Then just use the F5 button to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like CDspace said, However i would also like to add that if you have multiple QueryStrings in the URL, you don't use a question mark every time, the separator is an ampersand

```
URL:
http:localhost/sandbox?intValue=123&decimalValue=3.14&boolValue=true

C#    
public const string Q = "intValue";
public const string R = "decimalValue";
public const string S = "boolValue";

if (((Page.Request.QueryString[Q] != null)))
    ...
if (((Page.Request.QueryString[R] != null)))
    ...
if (((Page.Request.QueryString[S] != null)))
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Querystrings are key-value pairs. In typing in the browser, you'd have to include the value, i.e. `localhost/sandbox?UCT=123`, where UCT is the key, and 123 is the value. Click through for more info on the particulars of [`Page.Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)